# How to push git in windows?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have initialized Git in root project Windows.

I generated SSH(public, private) keys and put them in root project directory.

Generated SSH key I set in Bitbucker account.

Directory is empty.

After I did:

```
git add *
git commit -m 'G'
git push origin
```

After I get error:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

So, how can I bind my keys that to do authorized push to server?

Answer (score 0):

public & private key information should reside inside your user folder under a .ssh folder e.g. c:\Users\.ssh and should ideally be named id_rsa & id_rsa.pub.

There are configuration possibilities but this is the quick way

Also you should register your public key (the id_ras.pub) with your remove repository .for bitbucket it is under settings - ssh keys

Answer (score 0):

As @johnmem says, your SSH keys should not be in your project directory, and should definitely not be pushed to the repository!

Just keep them where ssh-keygen put them in the first place, and be sure to upload the `id_rsa.pub` file to BitBucket. If in doubt about the security of your private key, regenerate your key and remove its public key from all remote services!